# Python: how to fill out a web form and get the resulting page source

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to write a `python` script that will scrape http://www.fakenewsai.com/ and tell me whether or not a news article is fake news. I want the script to input a given news article into the website's `url` input field and hit the `submit` button. Then, I want to scrape the website to determine whether the article is "fake" or "real" news, as displayed on the website.

I was successful in accomplishing this using `selenium` and `ChromeDriver`, but the script was very slow (>2 minutes) and did not run on `Heroku` (using `flask`). For reference, here is the code I used:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def fakeNews(url):
  if url.__contains__("https://"):
    url = url[8:-1]
  if url.__contains__("http://"):
    url = url[7:-1]
  browser = webdriver.Chrome("static/chromedriver.exe")
  browser.get("http://www.fakenewsai.com")
  element = browser.find_element_by_id("url")
  element.send_keys(url)
  button = browser.find_element_by_id("submit")
  button.click()
  time.sleep(1)
  site = "" + browser.page_source
  result = ""
  if(site[site.index("opacity: 1")-10] == "e"):
    result = "Fake News"
  else:
    result = "Real News"
  browser.quit()
  return result

print(fakeNews('https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/02/opinion/sunday/instagram-social-media.html'))
```

I have attempted to replicate this code using other `python` libraries, such as `mechanicalsoup`, `pyppeteer`, and `scrapy`. However, as a beginner at `python`, I have not found much success. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction with a solution.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue you are experiencing here? From what I understand -- your script is working without issue, but you are running into problems during deployment to Heroku? I ran your code sample on my computer and it ran in 7 seconds, so I'm not sure how this is taking 2+ minutes. Where does the code seem to 'pause' the longest?

Comment: Locally, the script takes approximately 30 seconds to run for one headline on my website (created with `flask`). However, when the script is run for a collection of 20 headlines on one page, it takes 2-5 minutes.

Comment: On Heroku, I get the following error:
`The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`

Comment: The length of your script makes sense here then. 30 seconds per headline times 20 headlines is a total of 10 minutes, so 2-5 minutes is a steal. If you want to improve performance, you can re-write your script to not start a new Chromedriver instance every time. Instead, you can initialize just one Chromedriver, and run your headlines script against the single instance. Seems a few other users below have some ideas for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the stated purpose, in my opinion it would be much more simple to analyze the website, understand it's functionality and then automate the browser behavior instead of the user behavior.

Try to hit F12 on your browser while on the website, open the Network tab, paste a URL on the input box and then hit submit, you will see that it sends a HTTP OPTIONS request and then a POST request to a URL. The server then returns a JSON response as a result.

So, you can use Python's request module ([docs](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/)) to automate the very POST request instead of having a very complex code that simulates clicks and scrapes the result.

A very simple example you can build on is:

```
import json
import requests


def fake_news():
    url = 'https://us-central1-fake-news-ai.cloudfunctions.net/detect/'
    payload = {'url': 'https://www.nytimes.com/'}
    headers = {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '103', 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               'DNT': '1', 'Host': 'us-central1-fake-news-ai.cloudfunctions.net', 'Origin': 'http://www.fakenewsai.com',
               'Referer': 'http://www.fakenewsai.com/', 'TE': 'Trailers',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}

    response_json = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).text
    response = json.loads(response_json)
    is_fake = int(response['fake'])

    if is_fake == 0:
        print("Not fake")
    elif is_fake == 1:
        print("Fake")
    else:
        print("Invalid response from server")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fake_news()
```

PS: It would be fair to contact the owner of the website to discuss using his or her infrastructure for your project.

Comment: Great suggestion with the requests library. It sounds like Selenium is too slow for the user's needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The main slowdown occurs on starting a chrome browser and locating the first URL.
Note that you are launching a browser for each request.
You can launch a browser on the initialization step and only do the automation parts per request.
This will greatly increase the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I will give it a try and let you know if it works. Also, as this script will be running on a website, I was wondering if there was a way I could make it run without opening a Chrome window on the user's computer (using selenium or another method).

Comment: Chrome driver supports an option --headless which does not open browser. But in the background, the browser process is created and it takes similar time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there another method I could use (besides `selenium`) that would be quicker? This approach did improve the speed a bit, but still takes ~3-5 seconds per article. I have a news feed page that runs loads the script for the top 20 Google News headlines, so it takes over 1 minute to run, making the feature practically unusable.

Comment: 1 minute for a Selenium script is incredibly fast. UI automation is generally a slow and clunky process, and I commonly work with test cases that take 10-15 minutes for a single execution. It's just the nature of rendering a browser and simulating real user actions -- it takes time, just as it would take a real user time. If you want a faster solution, don't use UI testing at all. The `Requests` library in Python might be better here.

Comment: Oh, okay. I am still a beginner at python so I was not sure how to go about this project. The solution by @favic is working much better for me. Thanks for the help.